# Stateful LSTM fails to predict due to batch_size issue

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am able to successfully train my stateful LSTM using keras. My batch size is 60 and every input I am sending in the network is divisible by batch_size
Following is my snippet :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(80,input_shape = trainx.shape[1:],batch_input_shape=(60, 
trainx.shape[1], trainx.shape[2]),stateful=True,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(LSTM(40,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(40))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=1))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.005, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
```

My training line which runs successfully:

```
  model.fit(trainx[:3000,:],trainy[:3000],validation_split=0.1,shuffle=False,nb_epoch=9,batch_size=60)
```

Now I try to predict on test set which is again divisible by 60 , but I get error :

> ValueError: In a stateful network, you should only pass inputs with a
>   number of samples that can be divided by the batch size. Found: 240
>   samples. Batch size: 32.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong above ? I am confused , tried so many things but nothing helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that the reason for the error is that you did not specify the batch size in `model.predict`. As you can see in the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/#methods) in the "predict" section, the default parameters are

```
model.predict(self, x, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
```

which is why 32 appears in your error message. So you need to specify `batch_size=60` in `model.predict`.

Comment: Thanks , I thought it will be obvious for model to remember batch size it was trained on